# Drawing cfg using antlr4, graphiz and python and parser is empty

Tags: python, go, antlr4, lexer, control-flow-graph

I am using 2 files I will be sharing link if any doubt can visit one is cfg_from_stding.py and cfg_extractor_visitor.py and also I will share the lexer and go file go file is simple and correct.
I think in Lexer file something needs to be corrected or added.

On printing I am getting parse tree as : [] which means empty

```
def get_parse_tree(input_stream):
    lexer = GoLexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)

    # Print detailed information about lexed tokens
    print("Lexed Tokens:")
    for token in lexer.getAllTokens():
        print(f"Token: {token.type}, Text: '{token.text}', Line: {token.line}, Column: {token.column}")


    # Print lexed tokens
    print("Lexed Tokens:")
    for token in stream.tokens:
        print(token)

    parser = GoParser(stream)
    return parser.sourceFile()

def extract(input_stream):
    cfg_extractor = CFGExtractorVisitor()
    parse_tree = get_parse_tree(input_stream)
    print("Parse Tree:", parse_tree)  # Add this line to print the parse tree
    graph = cfg_extractor.extract(parse_tree)
    return graph
```

**EDITS**

```
def save_graphs(graphs, output_dir):
    import os
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    print(f"Total graphs to process: {len(graphs)}")

    for i, graph in enumerate(graphs):
        print(f"Processing graph {i}")
        try:
            output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"graph_{i}.png")
            nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', node_color='skyblue')
            plt.show()  # Display the figure
            plt.savefig(output_path)
            plt.close()
            print(f"Graph {i} saved to {output_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing graph {i}: {e}")

    print(f"All graphs processed and saved to {output_dir}")


def draw_CFG(graph, output_path, verbose=False):
    if isinstance(graph, list):
        print("Error: Received a list of functions instead of a graph.")
        return
```

[cfg_from_stdin.py](https://codefile.io/f/WuBTrXsBXD)

[cfg_extractor_visitor.py](https://codefile.io/f/ZrhVUK6Y9S)

[GoLexer.g4](https://codefile.io/f/XMvjUDVY6q)

[test.go](https://codefile.io/f/UHuSdOscEs)

Answer (score 2):

> On printing I am getting parse tree as : [] which means empty

Not necessarily. What happens if you do this instead:

```py
print("Parse Tree:", parse_tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

### EDIT

Also try to print the tree without messing around with the token stream to see if that prodcues the expected result:

```py
input_stream = ...
lexer = GoLexer(input_stream)
parser = GoParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
parse_tree = parser.sourceFile()
print("Parse Tree:", parse_tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

Otherwise, please update your question with enough code for others to reproduce the error (see: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have added all the file links do check once.
From the print line you suggested I am getting the following errors you may look into it to understand the problem:
Error during CFG extraction: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\iamsu\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\cfggo\go-visitor\src\cfg_from_stdin.py", line 83, in main     
    funcs = extract(stream)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\antlr4\atn\LexerATNSimulator.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.reset()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: The error I am getting now after implementing your edits:
Parse Tree : (sourceFile packageClause (eos <EOF>) <EOF>)

@bart I listed links of the files since there are multiple files so due to limitation I cannot add all the functions but upto what I have figured out the problem is with parser tree. I may be wrong you would know better I mean I am just sharing y views so I shared that part of the program.
I know it would be quite difficult to see all the file I have added 4 files 2py file 1 go file and 1 lexer file.
Kindly look into it so that we can solve the problem.

Comment: Type of 'funcs': <class 'dict'>
Content of 'funcs': {'functions': [], 'graph': []}       
line 1:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting 'package'    
Parse Tree: []
Visiting SourceFile
Parse Tree: []
Finished visiting SourceFile
----------------------------------------
Content of 'funcs' before saving graphs: []
Total graphs to process: 0
All graphs processed and saved to C:/Users/iamsu/OneDrive/Desktop/Programming/cfggo/go-visitor/test_output/

These are the errors graphs count is 0